# Find DataTable by DataTable.Id HELP!

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

There has to be an easy answer:
I want to loop through multiple datatables... 
example:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i ++ )
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable) "dt" + i.toString();

    // do something with DataTable dt1 as DataTable
    //  ie...

    int x = dt.Rows.Count
}
```

The above code obviously does not work.. but how do you find a DataTable like you do FindControl with WebControls?? I can't figure it out.

Comment: How do you normally refer to a `DataTable`? Are that local variables or something? Could you give an example of how you normally reference a `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, do you have

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt5 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt6 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
```

in your project?

You should then create a list of DataTables:

```
List<DataTable> datatables = new List<DataTable>();

datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt1 (now datatables[0])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt2 (now datatables[1])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt3 (now datatables[2])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt4 (now datatables[3])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt5 (now datatables[4])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt6 (now datatables[5])
datatables.Add(new DataTable());  // dt7 (now datatables[6])
```

Then you can loop like this:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in datatables)
{
    // do something with DataTable dt as DataTable
    //  ie...

    int x = dt.Rows.Count    
}
```

Comment: I need to access the data tables via a For Loop from another routine not as in a foreach... they are accessed individually..

Comment: I think your method may work though if I use List("dt" + i.toString()) or something like that?

Comment: @CraigJSte, they are accessed individually in a foreach loop, just as in a for-loop. But if you really want to get the i:th element you can do it like this `DataTable dt4 = datatables[4 - 1];` (datatables start the count from 0).

Comment: okay I will give you my code and you can see if this will work.. I can't get it to work.  I will post it later below...